# Selecting created option on menu close/select blur using creatable component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there some way to instruct `react-select` to select an option on menu close or select blur, but only if it is the one created (not from default list)?

**Context:**

I have a list of e-mail addresses and want to allow user to select from the list or type new e-mail address and then hit Submit button. I do the select part with `react-select`'s `Creatable` component and it works.

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

<CreatableSelect
    options={options}
    isMulti={true}
    isSearchable={true}
    name={'emailAddresses'}
    hideSelectedOptions={true}
    isValidNewOption={(inputValue) => validateEmail(inputValue)}
/>
```

But what happens to my users is that they type new e-mail address, do not understand they need to click the newly created option in dropdown menu and directly hit the Submit button of the form. Thus the menu closes because select's focus is stolen and form is submitted with no e-mail address selected.

I look for a way how can I select the created option before the menu is closed and the typed option disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the `inputValue` and add the `inputValue` as a new option when the `onMenuClose` and `onBlur` callbacks are triggered.

Keep in mind that both `onBlur` and `onMenuClose` will fire if you click anywhere outside of the select area. `onMenuClose` can also fire alone without `onBlur` if you press `Esc` key so you will need to write additional logic to handle that extra edge case.

```js
function MySelect() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const isInputPreviouslyBlurred = React.useRef(false);
  const createOptionFromInputValue = () => {
    if (!inputValue) return;
    setValue((v) => {
      return [...(v ? v : []), { label: inputValue, value: inputValue }];
    });
  };
  const onInputBlur = () => {
    isInputPreviouslyBlurred.current = true;
    createOptionFromInputValue();
  };
  const onMenuClose = () => {
    if (!isInputPreviouslyBlurred.current) {
      createOptionFromInputValue();
    }
    else {} // option's already been created from the input blur event. Skip.
    isInputPreviouslyBlurred.current = false;
  };
  return (
    <CreatableSelect
      isMulti
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={setInputValue}
      options={options}
      onMenuClose={onMenuClose}
      onBlur={onInputBlur}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit React - react-select Create New Option When Blur]

Comment: Wow, thank you @NearHuscarl for your response – more than I was hoping for!